# PHP for bold tags

Tags: php, regex

i am currently using

```
$value = preg_replace(array("<b>", "</b>"), array("<strong>", "</strong>"), $value);
```

but it is capturing even b's in text such as "new webinar"

I am trying to replace all b opening and closing tags with strong

Comment: that is $value = preg_replace(array("<b>", "</b>"), array("<strong>", "</strong>"), $value);

Comment: can you update you question, add some input and expected output

Answer (score 1):

In the first array of [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) you have to specify patterns with a delimiter, in this example `~`

Try it like this.

```
$value = preg_replace(array('~<b>~', '~</b>~'), array("<strong>", "</strong>"), $value);
var_dump($value);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/8oFdl)

Answer (score 1):

You  didn't specify any [delimiters](http://de.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) and since `<>` could be used as delimiters in PHP RegExes they are used instead. It means you are looking for `b` only by `<b>`. Correct way:

```
$value = preg_replace('~(</?)b>~', '$1strong>', $value);
```

Also you don't need Regular Expressions at all:

```
$value = str_replace(array("<b>", "</b>"), array("<strong>", "</strong>"), $value);
```